# setting minimum selectable date as 15 years past birthday (from mySQL) and max as current date

Tags: java, mysql, date, netbeans, datechooser

I have a mySQL table of users containing the users' birthdays.
i have stored the date from sql as the variable `DateOfBirth`.
Now, I want to set the minimum selectable date of a `jDateChooser` named `GameDateChooser` as 15 years past the birthday
and the maximum selectable date to the current date.
i tried searching for other articles but they didnt answer my question

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

From java doc there are [setSelectableDateRange](http://javadox.com/com.toedter/jcalendar/1.4/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#setSelectableDateRange(java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date)), which can accept two dates, min and max :

```
public void setSelectableDateRange(java.util.Date min, java.util.Date max)
```

In your case you need something like this :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -15);//15 year before
Date min = cal.getTime();

Date max = new Date();//actual date

JDateChooser jDateChooser = new JDateChooser();
//set your dates in your JDateChooser
jDateChooser.setSelectableDateRange(min, max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when `setSelectableDateRange()` requires two oldfashioned `Date` objects, I would still prefer to use the modern classes for the age calculation, not the outdated `Calendar`:

```
    LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.of(1959, Month.FEBRUARY, 15);
    Instant min = dateOfBirth.plusYears(15)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant();
    jDateChooser.setSelectableDateRange(Date.from(min), new Date());
```

`LocalDate` and `Instant` come built-in with Java 8 and later and are also available for Java 6 and 7. `Date.from(Instant)` is Java 8 and later only, for Java 6 and 7 there are other conversion options. A sufficiently new MySQL JDBC driver should be able to retrieve a `LocalDate` from the database.